# orders have disappeared from admin except 1

Tags: magento-1.7, orders

I am new on Magento and i am facing this issue
All orders have disappeared from admin panel except 
1. If possible please also advise cause of problem.. 
Please Help !!

Comment: Covering basics: did you clear the search filter?

Comment: A PLUGIN called FireGento_PDF did that to me. Uninstalled it and the problem was GONE.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like PHPMyAdmin to check the contents of your `sales_flat_order` table, if the orders are missing from this table they have been deleted.

Let me know what you see in this table, each record corresponds to an order.

**P.S**: Are you running multiple shops on your store? This could have something to do with a specific store view.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply `sales_flat_order` in this table showing all 41 records but not displaying in admin. and i am not running multiple stores..

Comment: Did this issue appear out of the blue or were there source file changes on your installation (i.e code change / module installation)?. Enable logging and check `system.log` and `exception.log` when you load that page. With shell you can use `tail -f system.log` | `tail -f exception.log`

Comment: Hi I am getting this from system.log . Notice: Undefined index: tartan  in /home/sites/example.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/tartan_finder/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml on line 36

Comment: This seems to be an issue on the frontend of your website which shouldn't cause the orders to be missing. Check the `text.phtml` file and make sure that the `$tartan` variable is defined prior to using it in a loop (this is on a completely separate note though). So nothing in the exception.log when you refresh your sales_order view?

Comment: okey thanks. there is nothing generate any exception.log file i have refresh more time but nothing heppend .. whats the cause of problem ?